# Ckeditor uploadimage 404 error / plugin setup

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to add the adding of images into with the editor, with drag 'n drop.

I wanted to update CK editor anyway, so after some reading I created a new CKeditor download via the package building, including the plugin uploadimage -
http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadimage

When I try to drag 'n drop an image in it, I'll see a green bar saying upload succesful and for less then a second I see the image in the editor. 
Then a red bar is showing. saying: 
'HTTP error occurred during file upload (404: File not found).'

I have this in the ckeditor config.js:

```
config.uploadUrl = '/upload/';
```

As I assumed this was the path were the images are uploaded. The folder is created and for testing I have set its permissions to 777.

As this is not working I assume I did something wrong here, or that I'm missing something in the configuration. But via the documentation I don't see what it might be.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

On a side note, I do not need/want a file browser. A little context -> this editor will be used by logged in users. I do not want one user be able to see images from the other and the input text in only used once, so no need to find earlier images as for this particular use the user will only use this editor once for setup. This is why I tought the uploadimage plugin would fit best for my needs.

Kind regards,

Martijn

Comment: Open the developers tool bar and check for errors in the console. Without the exact error it will be hard to help.

Comment: The requested URL /upload/ was not found on this
 server.

When putting the full url instead of just /upload/ doesn't work.
Then I was thinking it might search inside the folder ckeditor, so created a folder upload there with 777 permissions, but no luck.

Comment: You should read the documentation: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload

Comment: When I add the full url, it gives a different error:

    `[CKEDITOR] Error code: filetools-response-error. Object { responseText=""`

The documentation keeps refering to a upload.php... I do not see any or have any clue as to what needs to be in here. (I created a upload.php and set the imageUploadUrl) If i put 'TEST 1..2..3' in the upload.php the above error shows that as the response text...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload) of ckeditor:

> The `uploadUrl` setting contains the **location** of a **script** that handles file uploads of pasted and dragged images

This is **not** the folder in your server that you want to upload the files to. This should be the script that handles the submit of the file that should be uploaded, and this script is the one who handle the saving of the file in the relevant folder on the server.

> This plugin **only** covers the client side (what happen in the browser) and **not** the server side (which you need to implement by yourself).

Comment: I kind of came to the same conclusion, with the referal to the 'upload.php'.
Is it me or is it then quite strange that there is no documentation (none that I could find) on what needs to be in this server side script.

Can you point me to where I can find information about that?

Comment: Actually - it's all there. Read the documentation (the link in my answer).

Comment: I'm probebly still missing something. In the docs they mention this: `{
    "uploaded": 1,
    "fileName": "foo.jpg",
    "url": "/uploads/foo.jpg"
}` If i place this in the 'upload.php' It will not return any errors and it will put the link to an image foo.jpg located in uploads folder. This doesn't upload anything.

Comment: Your `upload.php` file should be a PHP script that does the actual uploading... the docs mention the output your script should generates in order for the CKEditor to be able to understand what happen with the file that was sent to the server (was it uploaded? whats the new name? what's it's path?)

Comment: Is it me, or is it a bit strange that this upload script is not included in the add-on, that in the discription seems to make it very easy.
I understand now what the script should output. I know how to do a fileupload via form, but this is drag n drop, does it still work the same with `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` ?

Comment: Actually it works **exactly** the same. The drag&drop is a client-side feature. The server side is exactly the same, you should only make sure you use the correct names (i'm not sure its `fileToUpload`)

Comment: Anyway - I think the answer is correct, so will appreciate if you can accept it and vote-up :)

Comment: Sorry, I have not done this before. Would you know how I can find out what it uses? fileToUpload was a placeholder for the comment. With that I can probebly make something happen. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check the `network` tab to see the name of the file that being sent, or use `var_dump($_FILES);` on the server.

Comment: And I learned something new again. it used 'upload', but got something working now. will have to finetune, but the basics work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: btw, you are welcome to check my [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5037551/dekel?tab=answers). you might find useful answers there (feel free to vote, but not too much...) :)